# Is it possible to auto-tweet using mergSocial in LiveCode?

Tags: livecode

mergSocial generates a modal window so a user can manually post a tweet. Is there a way to automate posting a tweet with mergSocial?

Comment: Please, provide more context / information. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I have a handler that executes mergTweet with a variable that contains the text. But mergSocial creates a modal stack above the app with a Post button. The user has to actually tap the Post button to post the tweet to Twitter (assuming the user is already logged into Twitter). Is there some way within LiveCode to simulate a user tapping the button. For example, with: send "mouseUp" to button "name". The problem is I don't know what the name of the button is in mergSocial's modal.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not currently possible to do that with mergSocial. To do that we would need to implement more of the Social framework that can do that kind of thing.